# Using a Raspberry Pi to Share WiFi Connection over Ethernet

Tags: raspberry-pi, internet-sharing, debian-wheezy

I have a Raspi successfully connected over WiFi, and I want to connect some wired devices to the same network through it. My AP already provides a DHCP server, so I basically want something to *bridge* the ethernet. I'm running debian (wheezy). Thoughts?

---

P.S. It seems bridging is the way to go, but following [this](http://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections) tutorial makes the Raspi WiFi connection drop.

Comment: did you properly identify your wireless connection and your ethernet connection... and bridge them in the proper order?  (wifi to ethernet) as opposed to doing it in the opposite direction?

Comment: Yes... I'm trying this to broadcast IPTV through WiFi. It seems I got it working, but I only get about 5 seconds of video, before it freezes, and looses the connection. Maybe there's something that is preventing this to act as a pure bridge?

Comment: You may suffer from power loss on the USB port where you have the Wifi dongle connected. You can try shorting out the polyfuses next to the USB ports to get more current. http://raspi.tv/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/polyfuse.jpg

Comment: This sounds like a power issue. Try using a powered hub or get rid of the Raspberry Pi and use Powerline Networking.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be usefull: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=14284
You can use an "Y" cable to get more power for usb dongle.

Comment: what are you even talking about? OP wanted to share his WiFi through Rpi's eth. YOu've linked to a thread which talks about finding a WiFi dongle/adapter for RPi.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having problems with setting up a wifi to wired bridge and found the following site. There is an install script or you can follow the steps outlined. It worked perfectly for me. http://hackhappy.org/uncategorized/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-to-create-a-wireless-to-wired-network-bridge/

Basically you're going to need DHCP and iptables setup and configured. DHCP is setup so install iptables with:

```
apt-get install iptables
```

Now configure your eth0 with a static ip and your wlan0 for DHCP. Add the following line to the end of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
up iptables-restore > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

Configure DHCP conf file, here is my sample /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

```
option domain-name "[Domain]";
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    subnet [Subnet] netmask [Netmask] {
    range [IP Range Start] [IP Range End];
option routers [IP];
```

To finish up execute the following commands to restart DHCP with new settings and setup IP forwarding:

```
 echo "INTERFACES=\"eth0\"" > /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
 service isc-dhcp-server restart
 update-rc.d isc-dhcp-server enable
 echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
 echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o [wlan0] -j MASQUERADE
 iptables -A FORWARD -i $wifid -o [eth0] -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A FORWARD -i [eth0] -o [wlan0] -j ACCEPT
 iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
 /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Please post all relevant information to your answer in your answer to avoid link rot